# Is it possible that weak memory is due to interference between signals in the brain?

Tags: human-biology, brain, memory

"Weak memory", as used in this question, refers to the inability to retrieve a memory that a person otherwise knows he has memorized earlier. An example of this is some fact snippet that the individual memorized as part of a training exercise 2 weeks earlier.

Is there scientific consensus for the cause of this type of weak memory? Or is the consensus that there are multiple causes?

Is it possible that this type of weak memory is caused by interference between various signals in the brain, or what does the known evidence say (if anything)?

Comment: It is better to use the term "weak memory" because people might think "bad memories" refer to memories of unpleasant events.

Comment: Weak memory can be either because of synapses not strengthened enough by [LTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_potentiation) or actual weakening because of [LTD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_depression), [synaptic pruning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synaptic_pruning), amnesia or even neurodegeneration.

Comment: Was reading about something along this topic earlier, kidney failure can result in poor short term memory -http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/2088591/.  Otherwise I would assume there are myriad causes for memory dysfunction

Comment: I would also add that cholinolytics which inhibit he action of choline cause memory loss and inability to retrieve memories of various levels. For example, the well-known cholinolythic trihexyphenydil causes one to forget the beginning of a sentense before the person comes to the end of the sentense and causes other memory losses. On the other hand, drugs that potentiate choline (like pramiracetam) cause significant memory improvements, even massive sudden recovery of long-lost child memories. This information is somewhat orthogonal to what you're asking, but I thought you might be interested.